# Why is selected not an option for React?

Tags: reactjs, default-value

I am having issues correcting mysyntax in a React project. I get the error "Warning: Use the `defaultValue` or `value` props on  instead of setting `selected` on ." However, I am unable currently to dynamically update the selected option for the drop down menu using just value/default value. The code updates 'correctly' when selected is used.

Relevant code below:

```
const Client  = ({..., reactions}) => {

...
     List Generator
 function ReactionList() {
                 // retrieve and filter reactions 
        const availableReactions = reactions.filter(...)
        return ( 
            availableReactions.map((reaction, index) =>
                <option key={index} value={reaction._id} selected={chosenReaction.name === reaction.name}>
                    {reaction.name}
                </option>
            )
        )
    }

    // selecting reaction from drop down
    function SelectReactionOption(entry){
        setSelectedReactionId(entry);
        setReactionPsiUpcast(0);
    }

return ( 
...
<div className="DropDown">
                <div>
                    <p>
                        Actions:
                    </p>
                    <select type="number" name={chosenAction.name} onChange={e => SelectActionOption(e.target.value) }>
                        <ActionList/>
                    </select>
                </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just move the entire `<select>...</select>` into the `ReactionList` component? Then it will become easy to use `defaultValue`.

Comment: Hello!

It makes sense. When i do that, the selected option which shows in the drop down menu requires to be clicked twice. Do you know why that might be?

 <option key={index} value={reaction._id} defaultValue={chosenReaction.name === reaction.name}>

Comment: Update! figured out the issue with defaultValue which was I had to change the variable i was calling. Thanks for the help!